# When I colour a long input string with termcolor "colored" it cuts the string

Tags: python, string, termcolor

I'm having a problem where when I colour an input string with termcolor "colored" it cuts the string. So basically if I made an input

```
int(input("hello my name is bob i like food do you like food i am a person and i like food and candy and cavities"))
```

And I colour it with termcolor "colored":

```
int(input(colored("hello my name is bob i like food do you like food i am a person and i like food and candy and cavities", "blue")))
```

Then it prints:

```
erson and i like food and candy and cavities food i am a pe
```

in blue.

Thanks, and it would be nice if someone could answer this.

Comment: The only way i could fix it was to add a bunch of spaces in the start of the text.

Comment: Try `print(repr(colored("hello my name is bob i like food do you like food i am a person and i like food and candy and cavities", "blue")))` and see what string value is being passed to `input()` as the prompt — it might give you a clue on what the problem is.

Comment: @martineau the string looks like `'\x1b[34mhello my name is bob i like food do you like food i am a person and i like food and candy and cavities\x1b[0m'`

Comment: That looks correct and what I would suspect, and ought be OK to use as the `input()` argument. Perhaps your console/terminal is mis-configured some way.